# The Documentation - Integration with the Q&A

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

We all know about the "Documentation" project that is being launched soon.

I wanted to suggest a few ideas.

## Reference in Q&A answers.

What if we could have an awesome integration with the Documentation into our answers.

Think of this.

We are going to have a HUGE compilation of documentation for the general population to search and Google.

Lets face it. The reason why people like the Q&A type setup is that they don't have to go looking through endless pages of documentation. I'm not saying it won't be helpful, I'm just saying...

Your average buddy that is trying to learn html is not going to know even if what they found in the documentation is actually what they want.

This is why I suggest a seamless integration with StackOverflow Q&A site. I have made a little mock-up of what a sample answer may look like:

[image]

### Edit / Sidenote

- To answer some questions.

This does not only need to be an example of the code. You could use it as a "Look at this part of the documentation" or just as like a "Here is the information you need".

There could be a popup, where you select the document you want to insert a part of (by means of search or by url)... when you enter the link you can select whether you want to insert the **entire document** (not recomended due to page size), **a section of the page** where you could highlight / select the parts you want, or just a **link** to the page (maybe that would scroll to a specific part of the document).

### End of sidenote

Idea being, unless the OP specifically needs code for his project we can just link it to, pre-created easy to access code samples from the documentation.

This will allow easy access to the documentation, for both the potentially "new" programmer that may not know what or where or how to look for it in the first place. But also just a reference to those who just need a point in the right direction!

We could also add features to make it possible to easily source facts. Providing easy, and reliable sources for all of our answers all of which would be from the "Documentation".

Comment: "*The reason why people like the Q&A type setup is that they don't have to go looking through endless pages of documentation.*" No, the reason we like Q&A is because you can find information that *isn't* in the documentation.

Comment: I don't understand your mock-up, because you didn't show what this answer would look like in Markdown. Is this linking to a particular part of Documentation, or just a "check out this other part of our site" link? Is this link created by the question writer, or does it happen automatically without their input? Is the code block shown in the answer sourced from Documentation, or written into the answer like normal?

Comment: @DanGetz I have added an edit to try and clear up some of your questions

Comment: "We are going to have a HUGE compilation of documentation for the general population to search and Google. " We already have that, haven't we? It's just not part of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7):

We've talked briefly about embedding Documentation stuff in Q&A, but any implementation (or even, really, buy-in on implementation) is a ways off. For one, examples aren't *just* code. They're fully-featured markdown, similar to answers here. Embedding an example as-is might not even turn out to be all that useful.

We do, however, have a way to link to topics and examples (and it includes a search), which should get us a bit closer to what you're envisioning here.

Comment: Okay. I think that documentation works to a degree, when people know what they are looking for. However it does not work if you are new to the topic and have no idea what is being documented, which is why it would be good to include "snapshots" which may contain snippets from the documentation

Comment: What about closing broad topics as duplicates of documentation topics? For example, someone asking about how to use a for loop in JavaScript. If that was covered in a documentation topic with examples, would it be possible to have that be a closure candidate?

Comment: Also, if being able to use this feature hinges on the success of the search implementation used to find useful parts of it, does that mean that there is going to be actual effort into improving the search feature overall?

Comment: @TrevorClarke I figure folks who do know can make the call on whether to link to something from docs or not. Were you thinking of something automatic instead, or...?

Comment: @TravisJ No plans on closing questions as duplicate of Docs at the moment. Search within Docs is a bit dicey right now, and there are plans to make it less so in near-ish future. We recognize that searching is pretty vital there.

Comment: Well, tbh I wasn't. My idea was more of a better way to quote the documentation. Instead of just coping the text you could have like a preview of the actual documentation in your answer... I added an edit titled "edit / sidenote". Also.. is there a google doc with info / ideas / changes to the "documentation" project? if yes where can I find it? Also how can I get into the beta? I would love to try it out but I have no idea how long it will take to get a response... thanks for your time

Comment: @TrevorClarke We are using the beta site to collect feature requests at the moment (and posting here is generally also fine, although the audience isn't quite right yet, but that's okay). [Signups are open](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/13ynCK-DEy0osod8VIENajnbFJNZxXm1jyeupBrl5v44/viewform) till the end of the month (and actual invites would take "some time" after that, though we plan to invite everyone who has signed up) but since you're already thinking of new features and whatnot... drop me an email (address is in my profile) and I'll see about hooking you up with access next week.

Comment: @AdamLear Thanks! Will do!